# translate within simple_form i18n

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, rails-i18n

I am trying to translate label but i don't understand clearly how to do it, even after reading docs.

my simple_form local, but in my language local

```
en:
  simple_form:
    labels:
      listener:
        new:
          email: "Your email"
          password: "password"
          remember_me: "remember me"
          password_confirmation: "confirm password"

      message:
        title: 'Title'
        description: 'Description'
```

and in my form view, to create new message, i want to translate label for title and description. In understand that message: stands for model name.

```
<%= simple_form_for @message, html: { multipart: true }  do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :title, label: "Message Title"  %>
  <%= f.input :description, label: "Short Description" %>
```

Comment: It looks right - have you tried restarting your server? The I18n files are loaded when the server starts and not on each request.

Comment: i did but still not working